# Code sign error in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign, build-error

Currently I am using the Xcode 3.2.5 i am getting problem in Code Signing on Distribution & Release **Don't Code sign** but when i selecting Release from Configuration list It's showing my all certificates Distributor and Developer both but why it's not showing any certificates on  Distribution & Release ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you select any certificates in the dropdown? Have you created a distribution certificate in the iTunes provisioning portal? You might start there first.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the Bundle identifier in the info plist file like
        `com.<yourCompanyName>.<projectName>`
then you can select the profile and code sign properly